# Can you re-make a method abstract in the inheritance tree?

Tags: java, inheritance, abstract-class, multiple-inheritance, abstract

EDIT:

To be clear: The fact that the design is quite ugly is not the point. The point is, that the design is there and I am in the situation to have to add another sub-class of `FlyingMotorizedVehicle` which would not work as expected if I forgot to add the `foo(...)`. So I just was wondering if I could redefine it as abstract.

---

I am right now facing a quite weird inheritance situation.
Lets say, I have three classes, `Vehicle`, `MotorizedVehicle` and `FlyingMotorizedVehicle` as well as a bunch of classes `Airplane`, `Helicopter`, ...:

```
public abstract class Vehicle {

    abstract Something doStuff(...);

    abstract SomethingElse doOtherStuff(...);

    abstract Foo bar(...);

}

public class MotorizedVehicle extends Vehicle {

    @Override
    Something doStuff(...) {
        return new Something();
    }

    @Override
    SomethingElse doOtherStuff(...) {
        return new SomethingElse();
    }

    @Override
    Foo bar(...) {
        return new Foo();
    }

}

public class FlyingMotorizedVehicle extends MotorizedVehicle {

    @Override
    SomethingElse doOtherStuff(...) {
        return new SomethingElse();
    }

}

public class Airplane extends FlyingMotorizedVehicle  {

    @Override
    Foo bar(...) {
        //do something different
        return new Foo();
    }

}

public class Helicopter extends FlyingMotorizedVehicle {

    @Override
    Foo bar(...) {
        //do something totally different
        return new Foo();
    }

}
[...]
```

So `Vehicle` is an abstract class providing some abstract methods. `MotorizedVehicle` is a sub-class of `Vehicle` with concrete implementations of its methods. `FlyingMotorizedVehicle` again is a sub-class of `MotorizedVehicle` overriding the implementations of a subset of `MotorizedVehicle`s methods.

Now there are the sub-classes `Helicopter`, `Airplane` and potentially some others which in the example override the concrete implemenatation of `MotorizedVehicle#bar(...)`.
What I want is to "force" every sub-class of `MotorizedVehicle` to have to override the `bar(...)` method and provide its own implementation.

Is it possible to just change the `FlyingMotorizedVehicle` in the following way:

```
public class FlyingMotorizedVehicle extends MotorizedVehicle {

    @Override
    SomethingElse doOtherStuff(...) {
        return new SomethingElse();
    }

    abstract Foo bar(...);

}
```

So that I just redefine the `bar(...)` as abstract method? My IDE is not complaining about it, but that of course does not mean, that it will actually work.

I hope you get what I try to point out here.

Thanks in advance

Bluddy

Comment: Your IDE should complain because `FlyingMotorizedVehicle` ist not abstract and non-abstract classes cannot contain abstract methods. Otherwise I this is possible. You can use it to force another subclass to reimplement the method. I've done this e.g. with `equals()` and `hashCode()` a few times.

Comment: Imho, it's more clear to refactor this to `Template method` pattern, having `doStuff(), ..., bar()` as template methods and have all subclasses separate implementations. If you want to share some code between subclasses, put that code is `protected static` methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, You have to redefine the `bar(...)` as abstract method. 
Then you have to declare `public class FlyingMotorizedVehicle` as a abstract class as well

```
public abstract class FlyingMotorizedVehicle extends MotorizedVehicle {

    @Override
    SomethingElse doOtherStuff(...) {
        return new SomethingElse();
    }

    abstract Foo bar(...);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You want children of `MotorizedVehicle` to have a default implementation of `bar`, but not so for the children of the `FlyingMotorizedVehicle`.

```
abstract class BasicMotorizedVehicle
    // no bar
    ... // Rest of old MotorizedVehicle

class MotorizedVehicle extends BasicMotorizedVehicle
    Foo bar(...) { ... }

class FlyingMotorizedVehicle extends BasicMotorizedVehicle
```

Answer (score 0):

Brother, study ***Interfaces*** too.

If you want some class, such as `Vehicle` to only provide function prototypes, then you should always use **Interface**.

And make your `FlyingMotorizedVehicle` as abstract class.

- *Abstract class can have both types of functions, either prototype only (abstrac functions) or fully implemented functions.*
- *Interfaces have only function prototypes, they can't contain function implementations, Interfaces are required to be implemented.*

For further study, you can find many useful links, including [this one.](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077421/learn-java/abstract-classes-vs-interfaces.html)

=============================CODE-EXAMPLE=======================================

**For Vehicle**

```
public interface Vehicle {

    Something doStuff(...);   
    SomethingElse doOtherStuff(...);
    Foo bar(...);

}
```

**For FlyingMotorizedVehicle**

```
public abstract class FlyingMotorizedVehicle extends MotorizedVehicle {

    SomethingElse doOtherStuff(...) {
        return new SomethingElse();
    } 
}
```

===============================================================================

Happy *OOP-ing*!

Comment: Thanks for the hints, though, the question was not about the hierarchy here or the design of it all. The example is also very short...the abstract class Vehicle is offering implementations as well as abstract prototypes. Maybe also the many "I"'s in my question are confusing, but I did not design that. What I just faced is the fact that a wanted to add one of the sub-classes (so another flying vehicle) and "forgot" to override the foo which let to a behaviour which I did not like :)

Comment: @Bluddymarri It is actually a design problem buddy. :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. In fact, it even says you can explicitly [in the language spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.3.1):

> An instance method that is not abstract can be overridden by an abstract method.

The problem you are facing is described a few paragraphs up:

> **The declaration of an abstract method mmust appear directly within an abstract class (call it A) unless it occurs within an enum declaration (§8.9); otherwise a compile-time error occurs.**

So, the problem is that your class is not abstract, as others pointed out already; it may just be useful to know the specific parts of the spec which describe it.